# Action 'utter_greet' doesn't correspond to a template / action. Module doesn't contain a class with this name

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am building one bot on RASA 1.9.4 and following is the error I've encountered:

The bot does not have any custom actions, just utter responses. The solution for this issue is not available on the internet, please help me in resolving the same.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa_core/actions/factories.py in _action_class(action_name)
     47         try:
---> 48             cls = utils.class_from_module_path(action_name)
     49             return cls()

8 frames
KeyError: 'utter_greet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa_core/actions/factories.py in _action_class(action_name)
     67                     "Module doesn't contain a class with this name. "
     68                     "Remember to prefix actions that should utter a template "
---> 69                     "with `utter_`. Error: {}".format(action_name, e))
     70 
     71     actions = []

ValueError: Action 'utter_greet' doesn't correspond to a template / action. Module doesn't contain a class with this name. Remember to prefix actions that should utter a template with `utter_`. Error: 'utter_greet'
```

The following are the utter_greet defined in my domain file and snapshot from story:

```
responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: Hey! This is Kia, Your personal assistant. How can i help you?

* greet
  - utter_greet
* AI_def
  -utter_AI_def
* AI_importance
  -utter_AI_importance
```

Comment: I have edited the question, do let me know if you need any further info

Comment: check the responses, you have `utter_greet1` and you're using `utter_greet` under `greet`

Comment: It's a typo error while i am editing it, i can assure you that names are alligned in  both doamin file and story file

Comment: The issue has been resolved.

The latest version of Rasa has responses in domain file instead of word templates. Since i have installed the Rasa NLU and CORE separately, CORE is unable to recognize the word responses. It's a small mismatch.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved.

The latest version of Rasa has responses in domain file instead of word templates. Since i have installed the Rasa NLU and CORE separately, CORE is unable to recognize the word responses. It's a small mismatch.